# how to get text from another app in android?

Tags: android

I want to receive in my app a text that was selected in some another android app.
I read about Intent class, but if I understood well, it need to send something from first app and after receive it in second one. But I can not control first app. Is it possible to solve this problem?

Thank you for advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a  `ContentProvider` is what you're looking for.
Have a look at these pages:

[Android Development Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

[Content Provider Tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_content-providers/)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no, it's not possible unless you are either the author of both applications (to where you can have the first app make the text available through some mechanism) or the first application provides a mechanism like a `ContentProvider` or something to fetch the information.